# App Store Connect error 2002: "ask your Account Holder to set up an App Store Connect account for you"

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm developing an iOS app for a client. I attempt to add him as a user under "Users and Access" using his apple ID email address. He receives the invite and enters his apple ID and password, but receives this error message:

"Unable to Sign In" - "This app is used by developers to manage apps on the App Store. To get access, ask your Account Holder to set up an App Store Connect account for you. (2002)"

Under Users and Access, the user record is grayed out as though he hasn't accepted the invitation, and I can't add him as a tester in the app yet.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

For anyone facing this issue:

I faced the same problem today, deleting the invitation and sending it again worked.

FYI: First I had sent an invitation with the role "Developer" and later with the role "Admin", which might have had something to do with it working

Comment: for me helped to avoid the app, browsr login worked fine

Answer (score -2):

just remove the invite and do it again, it is better if the team is coordinated and understands how the aggregation process works

Answer (score -2):

The first time This app is used by developers to manage apps on the App Store. To get access, ask your Account Holder to set up an App Store Connect account for you. (2002)